# Restrict generic typescript type to single string literal value, disallowing unions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic entity type, with the generic used to define a field type based on a set of string literals:

```
type EntityTypes = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

type EntityMappings = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
  baz: Array<string>;
}

type GenericEntity<T extends EntityTypes> = {
  type: T;
  fieldProperty: EntityMappings[T];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is require all instances of GenericEntity to have a single `type` field (a string literal) that then defines the type of fieldProperty, e.g:

```
const instance: GenericEntity<'foo'> = {
  type: 'foo',
  fieldProperty: 'hello',
};

const otherInstance: GenericEntity<'baz'> = {
  type: 'baz',
  fieldProperty: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
}
```

However, because `T extends EntityTypes` allows for a union of multiple string literal values in EntityTypes, I'm able to do this, which I want to disallow:

```
const badInstance: GenericEntity<'foo' | 'baz'> = {
  type: 'baz',
  fieldProperty: 'blah',
};
```

This compiles because now `type` is of type `'foo' | 'baz'` and fieldProperty is of type `string | Array<string>`, but the two fields no longer correspond like I intend them to.

Is there a way to restrict the generic declaration on GenericEntity further, to only allow a single unique string literal value? Barring that, is there some other way to insist that any instance of GenericEntity has a `type` field and a `fieldProperty` field that correspond?

Comment: Glad you undeleted this.  Was halfway through writing up an answer and then it vanished

Comment: I saw a duplicate after submitting, but realized after some further thought that this was actually asking about a slightly different use case! Thanks for the answer, looks perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no direct way to restrict a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter to a single member of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) to support something like `T extends oneof EntityTyes`, but that's not implemented yet.  If you want to see it happen you might visit that issue and give it a , but I don't know it would have much effect.

That means `T extends EntityTypes` could allow `T` to be any subtype of `EntityTypes`, including the full `EntityTypes` union.  In practice this tends not to be a huge deal, since usually such `T` does get inferred as a single member (people often call `foo("x")` or `foo("y")` instead of `foo(Math.random()<0.5?"x":"y")`).  But sometimes it causes problems, especially with example code like yours.

---

So how can we work around this?  Given your particular example code, I'd say that you want `GenericEntity` to actually be more like a discriminated union with three members, instead of a generic type.  But you can get both, via a *distributive object type* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It looks like this:

```
type GenericEntity<T extends EntityTypes = EntityTypes> = { [U in T]: {
  type: U;
  fieldProperty: EntityMappings[U];
} }[T]
```

We are taking the type `T` passed in and [mapping over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) its members, and then [indexing into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `T`.  This has no real effect if `T` is a single string literal, but when it's a union, the result is also a union without any of the undesirable "cross-correlated" terms:

```
type GE = GenericEntity;
/* type GE = {
    type: "foo";
    fieldProperty: string;
} | {
    type: "bar";
    fieldProperty: number;
} | {
    type: "baz";
    fieldProperty: string[];
} */
```

(I also made a [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for `T` so `GenericEntity` without a type argument is the full union we actually want here.)

So what we're doing is: instead of *prohibiting* unions in `T`, we are *handling them* by distributing over them.

Now things will behave as you desire:

```
const instance: GenericEntity<'foo'> = {
  type: 'foo',
  fieldProperty: 'hello',
} // okay;

const otherInstance: GenericEntity<'baz'> = {
  type: 'baz',
  fieldProperty: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
} // okay

const badInstance: GenericEntity<'foo' | 'baz'> = {
  type: 'baz',
  fieldProperty: 'blah',
}; // error!
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAKuCBnKBeKByAMwHsi8oAffAIwEMAnMyvWgLzwG4AoT0SWBZCACyNMGERwA5llwBvTlCjEiALigZgdCZK6LadNXACuAWyoQ6uqKzUBBOnRogAPBq1SAfFwC+3XtABxCDgLRABjeCRQZxQoCAAPYGCAEyxIwTRIGX4okEzMDxwoWSgAbQBVKAkoFABdNXlFfzVyqwJECAAbZIAFOiJIOlA1dNARMW0MCtqfKG9Sur90KACYIqCQrQiBUC4AegAqKH8VtbkFRWP0NQAiZRurRXau3v7B4fVNbVnKRsvmqA3fQPC5PDrdPoDCwfYxmCw-Yqgq6QW6sEGXJTg15QoYgNRubSlGacbxQA57bhhIhwDRVGnAGhwMIQNQbULbXLOQgkPCFc5Na74ZR4AA0F2eELe0Lx+AAFl1OqQxaS9nsoEQANZOLicKn09XAeV0ACS9MZzNZwXZoxczBobD5iIFKOo9tF4qxkPeMtKeBoouoAbwYTwtWVUFV6q1IEp1NptGSpo05pZKytWxtXOFFFdDqKfwBdrYYrBLy90rUzE6NFl7u87Ajaos-ToAEIgA)