# How to constrain a union type to a specific type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

```
type MyMap = {
  a: () => void
  b: (s: string) => void
  c: (n: number) => void
}
type MyKey = keyof MyMap
function wrapper(fn: MyMap[MyKey]) {
  return async function(...arg:Parameters<MyMap[MyKey]>){
    await Promise.resolve();
    fn.apply(null, arg);
  }
}
```

It should work because I know I pass a `fn` to `wrapper`, and `fn.apply` the same `arg`. But Typescript throws an error:

```
The 'this' context of type '(() => void) | ((s: string) => void) | ((n: number) => void)' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type '(this: null) => void'.
  Type '(s: string) => void' is not assignable to type '(this: null) => void'.
    Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 1 or more, but got 0.
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiMEMxQLxQN4CgpQQLigAoBKVAPigDcB7ASwBNsoAjAwgZwPeACdaA7AOakUFGgyYBjNvwL8ArgFtmEHiLF1GAX0yhIsEAGkIIVFADWJ6gDMDiMJmvz%20k4LWr8oAdx5JIPQmtZOyQAbThjEABdUiwcHghgeR5PBHYQFygnFzcPQgA6QoQeQTwABWKERUTVdgAeOHtwoxMosmI4nFwvBFpgKDKeakVadgh8hPZqABtKCBIAbiYcIPy-aZBCBWnpgBpcEuIlnB0tIA)

Comment: You have to use `any`s in this case `(fn as (...a: any[])=>void)(...arg)`

Comment: Where is there an "enum" in this question?

Comment: It looks like you should use a generic, not a union

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I mean union types 

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's possible to solve this in the way that you want but hopefully @jcalz can swoop in and correct me.

As to why your current implementation doesn't work, `keyof MyMap` is actually the union of all possible keys in `MyMap`, i.e. `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`. Inside your `wrapper` function you are essentially saying

```
function wrapper(fn: MyMap['a' | 'b' | 'c']) {
  return async function(...arg:Parameters<MyMap['a' | 'b' | 'c']>){
    await Promise.resolve();
    fn.apply(null, arg);
  }
}
```

`arg` is therefore inferred to be `[] | [s: string] | [n: number]` as `Parameters` distributes across `MyMap['a']`, `MyMap['b']` and `MyMap['c']`

You can see why by the time you're trying to apply `arg` to `fn`, TypeScript doesn't know the type of `fn` and how it relates to the type of your `...arg` so it complains

---

Ideally what you want is to tell TypeScript that you are only accessing 1 function on the `MyMap` type so the downstream typing will work in the context of a single function

You may be tempted to try something like this

```
function wrapper<K extends keyof MyMap>(fn: MyMap[K]) {
  return async function(...arg:Parameters<MyMap[K]>){
    await Promise.resolve();
    fn.apply(null, arg);
  }
}
```

but you will encounter the same issue because we are still extending `keyof MyMap` which is the union of all keys.

Even though in practice we would use it as follows

```
const someAFn: MyMap['a'] = () => {} // valid
wrapper<'a'>(someAFn)                // types match
```

from inside the function TypeScript still has to protect for the use case where `K` is not just a union of a single type (e.g. `'a' | 'b'`, which is a perfectly valid `keyof MyMap`)

As far as I know, there is currently no way to inform typescript to [restrict a generic expecting a union type to a single member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913279/restrict-generic-typescript-type-to-single-string-literal-value-disallowing-uni)

---

Instead of dealing with `MyMap` directly from within `wrapper`, you could instead extract your function before passing it into `wrapper` and just infer the arguments from there. This guarantees that you will only ever be passing a single function of a fixed signature into `wrapper` which TypeScript can easily deal with

```
function wrapper<T extends (...args: any[]) => void>(fn: T) {
  return async function(...arg:Parameters<T>){
    await Promise.resolve();
    fn.apply(null, arg);
  }
}

const someAFn: MyMap['a'] = () => {}
const someBFn: MyMap['b'] = (someString: string) => {}
const someCFn: MyMap['c'] = (someNumber: number) => {}

const aFn = wrapper(someAFn) // () => Promise<void>
const bFn = wrapper(someBFn) // (s: string) => Promise<void>
const cFn = wrapper(someCFn) // (n: string) => Promise<void>
```

I imagine this goes against the essence of what you are trying to achieve with a "wrapper function", but it hopefully sheds some light on where the difficulties arise

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=68&pln=37&pc=108#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiMEMxQLxQN4CgpQQLigAoBKVAPigDcB7ASwBNsoAjAwgZwPeACdaA7AOakUFGgyYBjNvwL8ArgFtmEHiLF1GAX0yhIsEAGkIIVFADWJ6gDMDiMAG5MmAPQuoAWi-efvv-4DAoKDna3l%20SWBaan4oAHceJEgeQmtZOyQAbThjEABdUiwcHghgeR5YhHYQCKgwiKiYwgA6VoQeQTwABXaERVLVdgAeOHtsoxM8smIinFw4hFpgKC6eakVadghmkvZqABtKCBInObr%20ZqT9kEIFff2AGlwO4lOoHR1Xd2Cf37--0LhSLRWIJJKqACiAEd5LRKAh9hB%20MBUulRlkAOQIDFQAA%20UAxzBx%20IxkgxBQwTBKZQquGqtXqwKarUuHW6vX6wEGI3gmOxeIJRIFpPJ01mOAQCyWKzWGy2Owge0Ox1eTBwaUuYDA11u8nuT3awjeH2cbk8-wtlotgIaIPiiS1qgA6ksABa5AAy1Go5nkYCGhigEAAHlz%20PR2BYrLZ0WAyKiCLHMoYKbNqeVKvTJHUgY1%20C02myeolOdykymxWr5otlqt1pttrsDkcTlWNVcbndHs8jUwTV9zVah8O-DamaCHckAGL8ADy-GuQwAKkHQ0iI0QWYbOLh%20CBMhTRFRNPG0gQl8Q2Fu2SsOQMeMMl9NyDL61shuJ6BQ06UM3SatmjJ5gWrKdMWfT3o%20lZnJKNavnKjaKs2KpvOqFwdrq%20o9qqOD9pIMTcFAez9AAgjOia8mAmRYuSZgkC%206A6Ph-CEcREAAELkRkVGErRaAcOsEAAMq8AInREaJQjqBgTEEcsbEAMJcUmIp5HRbEAHJKCoPByNpqjSYxzjMYRCAzmYYKOjwM7zjqbFkfwxCYCZyzMOZaCWdOc4LjcbGcY5zlyVAkjufa4LWd5dmCUpAVAA)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript can't follow the sort of correlation between the [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `MyMap[keyof MyMap]` (a union of three function types) and the `Parameters<MyMap[keyof MyMap]>` (a union of three [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)).  Your intention is that when the former is `(s: string) => void` then the latter will be `[string]`, but the compiler is worried about possible mismatch.  The general issue about the lack of language support for *correlated union types* is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The recommended approach to such cases is to refactor to a simple "base type" and then perform [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.  This is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

For your example, that would look like this:

```
interface MyMapArgs {
  a: [],
  b: [s: string],
  c: [n: number]
}

type MyMap = {
  [K in keyof MyMapArgs]: (...args: MyMapArgs[K]) => void
}
```

The base type is `MyMapArgs`, which directly represents the parameter tuples.  And now `MyMap` is a mapped type over `MyMapArgs`.  Your function then needs to be made generic in `K extends keyof MyMap`, and you can then talk about `MyMapArgs[K]` (a simple indexed access type) directly instead of `Parameters<MyMap[K]>` (using [the `Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) which is implemented as a more complicated [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that the compiler can't reason much about):

```
function wrapper<K extends keyof MyMap>(fn: MyMap[K]) {
  return async function (...arg: MyMapArgs[K]) {
    await Promise.resolve();
    fn.apply(null, arg); // okay
  }
}
```

That compiles just fine.

---

Unfortunately that you will immediately run into the fact that when you call the function, the compiler cannot narrow the type of `K` to the appropriate member (there is no value of type `K` sent to the function), and therefore the return type is inaccurate:

```
const w = wrapper((s: string) => console.log(s.toUpperCase()));
// const w: (...arg: [] | [s: string] | [n: number]) => Promise<void>

await w(123); // oops, this is allowed
//  RUNTIME ERROR: s.toUppercase is not a function
```

Probably the best way to deal with this is to explicitly make some use of `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`:

```
function wrapper<K extends keyof MyMap>(k: K, fn: MyMap[K]) {
  return async function (...arg: MyMapArgs[K]) {
    await Promise.resolve();
    fn.apply(null, arg);
  }
}
```

*Now* when you call it the compiler narrows as expected:

```
const w = wrapper("b", (s: string) => console.log(s.toUpperCase()));
// const w: (s: string) => Promise<void>
```

That argument is unneeded at runtime, but it really helps the compiler understand what you're doing.  If you want to avoid that then the compiler will not follow your logic and the best you can do is use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like, since functions at runtime do not carry information about their expected argument types.

```
function wrapper<F extends MyMap[keyof MyMap]>(fn: F) {
  return async function (...arg: Parameters<F>) {
    await Promise.resolve();
    (fn as any).apply(null, arg); // <-- need to assert here
  }
}

const w = wrapper((s: string) => console.log(s.toUpperCase()));
// const w: (s: string) => Promise<void>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE9VwA4EEoDmAzsgN4BQyycAXMgNoC6ANJcgEZ31F1FhSgCLNgi4g6IAK4BbdtEbkAvuXJh02FBizZkAXjJt6AaWShkAawjoA9jDSYc+YozoAKAHSe4hHve1OiY0YASj0APmQAN2tgABMlFRhJEAQwYGsQZAB3KBwNKAAeEwgAD0gQWJJLGzstHDDXGHE-HCDQiiooCDBJKEy4InQU5CSUtIzkDy9COjq8HzaDKio4LLhgMGQABShraWAiCHcuomsAG0iIV2CAbjYqJvc8s-RXKTOz5mpCW7ZlZXIAyGCBGyVS6UykD41yWyH46FhVAQGT42T02Vy2Hyrlcvj4AhABFCugiyJApzORzO1gIuPcYGsAFUsdAAMIDK7BLl3ZbIAD0fOQZNRWTcnieMwYjGQAB8GHj+IJpXL6M0pLJ5MSIjs9gcIAVonEwvdqGsNtlXABGABMAGZbvzBdZrNgiF8iPSmSyoAgOaYSCBrJs4KCxhC-kK4GAEAALSYQdom4XnKk01wJv4JVQQaG-cijcETHJ5aDWorIUrlSoWKy2FrYBrmOhGL5NWYObCLDrILo9PrUQbDAvjTJTCUEdv+BZGEKI03rTY6-aHY4586Xa485aPZ6vd6fb5Erf-FRAodgkdwnNga0w7vwufCzZZdHF723gBE7A-X1xvEVhJakKKIpu41K0h6DLMvk7KHNc3ImgKwHks+bgKgSRLhNsuzLvqhqxMaVCKJG0Zxumia8smlJgWmGZEVmUI3puiQXhCGIllAtoFAAYhWZQQBUJBzPQ1R1nMjANG2yDcRRPbdL0-SDiCw5sWO3gTts3hwNI3TQEQPFhLJKxmouOF6quFIbr8vKNIp1AgOgwRPFiLxvJIHxfOp1nICegJKaGhaQtetp3mwD7dkiKLPq+mL5CFf7IPighAVRqYQZ60Fshy8HeVQSFPtkaH-hhQFLnqBoxAREa+qR8ZGchFJpeRmbKEAA)

Comment: Thanks! It works very well in my situation!

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)