How can we relate two function parameters in TypeScript, in a generic function?
I am struggling adding the right types for function parameters, where the function should be generic and the parameters should relate to each other.
Here is a minimal reproducible example (in the actual code, the type Foo and the object objectOne come from a library that I cannot change, and the function func is one I am trying to create myself):
interface Foo {
  union: 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
  object: {
    One: {'oneRelatedKey': 'oneRelatedValue'};
    Two: {'twoRelatedKey': 'twoRelatedValue'};
    Three: {'threeRelatedKey': 'threeRelatedValue'};
  };
};

const objectOne = {
  one: {
    func: (obj: Foo['object']['One']) => {console.log(obj)}
  },
  two: {
    func: (obj: Foo['object']['Two']) => {console.log(obj)}
  },
  three: {
    func: (obj: Foo['object']['Three']) => {console.log(obj)}
  },
};

const func = <T extends Foo['union']>(one: T, two: Foo['object'][Capitalize<T>]) => {
  objectOne[one].func(two);
}

I am getting an error on two:
Property ''twoRelatedKey'' is missing in type '{ oneRelatedKey: "oneRelatedValue"; }' but required in type '{ twoRelatedKey: "twoRelatedValue"; }'

I want to ensure that func is called with a string from Foo['union'] and the corresponding object from Foo['object'], indexed on the capitalized version of the passed in Foo['union'] argument.
It should then work to call func as follows:
func('one', { 'oneRelatedKey': 'foo' })

Note: Only the parameter types should be changed, not the type of objectOne (the object comes from a library and the MRE is a simplified version).

I tried the following, and it seems closer:
type FirstTestGeneric<T extends Foo['union']> = T;
type FirstTest = FirstTestGeneric<'one'>; // 'one'

type SecondTestGeneric<T extends Foo['union']> = Capitalize<T> extends keyof Foo['object'] ? Foo['object'][Capitalize<T>] : never;
type SecondTest = SecondTestGeneric<'one'>; // {'oneRelatedKey': string}

const testFunc = <T>(one: FirstTestGeneric<'one'>, two: SecondTestGeneric<'one'>) => {
  objectOne[one].func(two);
}

Now I just need to somehow modify testFunc so it uses the type parameter. For some reason, this does not work:
const testFunc = <T extends Foo['union']>(one: FirstTestGeneric<T>, two: SecondTestGeneric<T>) => {
  objectOne[one].func(two);
}

I think the problem is that the type T accepts a union. If it just accepted one string (from the union Foo['union']), it would probably work.

I found the following: Restrict generic typescript type to single string literal value, disallowing unions
Trying to apply that here, we can do:
type GenericType<T extends Foo['union'] = Foo['union']> = { [U in T]: {
  type: U;
  parameter: Foo['object'][Capitalize<U>];
} }[T];


const testFuncOne = <T extends Foo['union']>(input: GenericType<T>) => {
  objectOne[input.type].func(input.parameter);
}

We still get this error on func(input.parameter):

Property ''twoRelatedKey'' is missing in type '{ oneRelatedKey:
string; }' but required in type '{ twoRelatedKey: string; }'

For some reason, func is expecting an argument of the following type:
(property) func: (obj: {
    oneRelatedKey: string;
} & {
    twoRelatedKey: string;
} & {
    threeRelatedKey: string;
}) => void

I have a sneaking suspicion this has something to do with functions being contra-variant in their parameters.

Not the DV but this doesn't really make sense to me, if you just make Foo a union type of { name: string; object: { "key": "value" } for the distinct combinations then the problem goes away. If that's satisfactory I'll write it up as an answer, otherwise what am I missing here?

@JaredSmith Note: The example is an MRE. In the actual code, the type and object comes from a library that I cannot change, and the function func is one I am trying to create myself.

It does work to call func as e.g. func("one", { oneRelatedKey: "oneRelatedValue" }) - these types work outside func. But inside func, T isn't yet specified; it's "one" | "two" | "three", so objectOne[one] could be any of those methods and two could be any of those objects and they're not all mutually compatible.

@jonrsharpe Exactly, so I need to narrow it with a conditional statement. See my edit.

It's possible with a little type manipulation:
interface Foo {
  union: 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
  object: {
    One: {'oneRelatedKey': 'oneRelatedValue'};
    Two: {'twoRelatedKey': 'twoRelatedValue'};
    Three: {'threeRelatedKey': 'threeRelatedValue'};
  };
}

type OneObjType = {
  [K in Foo['union']]: { func: (x: Foo['object'][Capitalize<K>]) => void }
}

const objectOne = {
  one: {
    func: (obj: Foo['object']['One']) => {console.log(obj)}
  },
  two: {
    func: (obj: Foo['object']['Two']) => {console.log(obj)}
  },
  three: {
    func: (obj: Foo['object']['Three']) => {console.log(obj)}
  },
};

const retyped: OneObjType = objectOne; // NOTE: type-safe, no cast

const func = <T extends Foo['union']>(one: T, two: Foo['object'][Capitalize<T>]) => {
  retyped[one].func(two);
}

Note that the signature of your original function was correct and I haven't modified it. The trick is to get the compiler to accept that the parameters to the methods in objectOne map back to the union and that the union connects to the corresponding objects in the Foo interface by using the alias retyped. Note also this is a reinterpreting of the type not a cast: the compiler still ensures safety.
Playground
Edit based on comments:
The reason this works but your original code doesn't has to do with the type of objectOne, which you index into and call a method on in the body of func. The compiler does not understand that the keys in objectOne are related to Foo['union'] and that the parameters to the func methods of that object relate to the values of Foo['object']. All the information to determine that is available, we humans can see it, but the compiler has to infer the most general type it can (and in the 99% case that's actually the behavior you want) so it can't just assume what you want it to here.
There are a couple of ways to override that behavior, one is to use the as const qualifier to tell the compiler to infer the narrowest type it can rather than the widest. But that would require modifying the annotation of the actual objectOne value, which you can't do since you're getting it from a 3rd party library (it also won't work if objectOne is mutable and not truly const, as const will make properties readonly).
Another way though is to connect the dots for the compiler by assigning an existing value to a compatible but narrower type (than the one it already has), which is the approach I've taken here: I extract a mapped type from Foo called OneObjType that makes explicit how the keys and func method parameters map back to Foo.
For a simplified example of the "assign to an alias with a narrower type", consider the following:
const x: 'a' | 'b' = 'a';
const y: 'a' = x; // legal narrowing assignment

function foo(a: 'a') {}
foo(x);  // ERROR: cannot assign 'a' | 'b' to 'a'
foo(y);  // Fine, no error!
x === y; // true

Even though 'a' is a narrower type than 'a' | 'b' the assignment to y is legal because the term-level value is a const and the compiler can prove it's safe. You can then use y in a place that requires the literal type 'a', but you can't use x because you can't use 'a' | 'b' to satisfy a type that requires 'a'. This is true even though y is just an alias for x. They point to the same term-level value (the string literal 'a') but x and y have different types, and you can do things with one you can't with the other (like pass to foo).
Making the assignment const retyped: OneObjType = objectOne; doesn't change objectOne at all, it just creates a new name for it that has a different but compatible type (which is why the compiler allows the assignment), and we can safely call the related methods by using that different view of the object: retyped[one].func(two); works because retyped is just an alias for objectOne but it has a different type, one that the compiler understands maps back to the Foo interface. It's just a way to tell the compiler to treat objectOne as the narrower type OneObjType rather than the type it already has when we refer to it via the retyped alias.
This isn't that different than using type narrowing via conditional checks except that it happens purely at compile-time, there's no runtime code that needs to execute to narrow the type, making for a more elegant solution.
Note that all of this works even if you get Foo and objectOne from a library because we don't modify either one of them at all, we just spell out the relation they have to each other so the compiler can understand it.

Thank you Jared, but I would like to avoid changing the signature of objectOne / use the same function. The MRE is a highly simplified version, in reality the type is much more complex. See my EDIT in the OP. I think this can be done with conditional types. All I seem to be missing is how to restrict a type parameter to be one string from a union, instead of T extends 'one' | 'two' | 'three' where T can be one but also 'one' | 'two'.

@jcalz wrote an answer which seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913279/restrict-generic-typescript-type-to-single-string-literal-value-disallowing-uni. Not sure how to apply it yet.

"I would like to avoid changing the signature of objectOne / use the same function" I didn't change anything, I literally copy/pasted your code. All I'm doing is narrowing the type of objectOne by reassigning it to a narrower but still compatible type, much the way the satisfies operator does (or conditional types for that matter). "The MRE is a highly simplified version, in reality the type is much more complex" then it isn't a MRE: I've answered the actual question you asked. If that doesn't solve your problem then that's fine, we often discover new constraints as we go.

But the correct etiquette would be to ask a follow on question with the appropriate constraints rather than invalidate an existing answer. I guess I still don't understand how this doesn't fix the issue: that mapped type I wrote doesn't care if there are 3 members of the union or 100... but that's probably a conversation for a follow on

The question remains the same, with the clarification that only the parameter types of func should be changed, not the type of objectOne.

@Magnus why? I'm not actually changing the type. You could move all that same logic inside of func and it would still work. You don't need to like go into your node_modules folder and change the type or anything crazy...

I see what you did, and I can try to apply it to my code. However, are you able to add an alternative where only the parameters' types are changed? Not only will it be easier in my case, but conditional types are also the most common way to tie parameters into each other (for example: https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/)

I have been playing around with your answer, but do not understand how or why it works. For some reason, func has changed what it expects to receive in your version vs the OP.

@Magnus "I...do not understand how or why it works" a left an edit to the answer that explains the slight but crucial difference from your original code.

Thank you. Do you have a link to the handbook (official docs) that details this or similar behavior, by any chance? Should I assume it isn't possible to make the compiler understand the relation by working on the parameter types only? Is that noted anywhere in the docs (all guides I have read talk about distributive conditional types to make such a connection)?

"Should I assume it isn't possible to make the compiler understand the relation by working on the parameter types only?" correct, because the problem is that you type the parameters with types from Foo but you use them to index into objectOne which isn't tied to Foo in the way you need it to be. You could possibly solve this by extracting the types for the parameters from typeof objectOne but they would not be related to Foo (at least as far as the compiler is concerned). As far as the documentation IDK but consider the following: const x: 'a' | 'b' = 'a'; const y: 'a' = x;

Even though 'a' is a narrower type than 'a' | 'b' the assignment to y is legal because the term-level value is a const and the compiler can prove it's safe. You can then use y in a place that requires the literal type 'a', but you can't use x because you can't use 'a' | 'b' to satisfy a type that requires 'a'. This is true even though y is just an alias for x. They point to the same term-level value (the string literal 'a') but x and y have different types, and you can do things with one you can't with the other. My answer is just that same idea adapted to your code.

It's also funny that you mention distributive conditional types, because that's the first approach I tried to solve this. But it failed because it doesn't actually solve the problem: it's just distributing something across Foo['union'] but the problem is that the distributed types still don't clarify the relationship to objectOne. Once you clarify that relationship for the compiler the problem goes away, and distributed conditional types aren't actually needed (they're just superfluous complexity in this particular case). Sorry for the wall 'o text, hope that cleared it up.

That is incredibly helpful and the exact depth I needed to understand the problem/solution better. Thanks again! I have no doubt it will be helpful to others as well. Some of this should really be added to the docs.

Jared, I looked into your a / b example, and I think I spotted something wrong (unless I misunderstood you). The only reason you can assign x to y is because you already narrowed x down to literal type a (which is the same type as y). If x was actually a wider type than y the assignment would never be allowed: const x: 'a' | 'b' = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'a' : 'b'; const y: 'a' = x; // error. It does not matter whether it is a const declaration or not, i.e. changing to let does not have an impact on the assignability of x to y.

Check out the playground here (hover your mouse over x then over m, m corresponds to x in your example and it is of type a after the first assignment): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgcgIbJgHxQIwwXhgFlUoALAOgCdUwATEAWwAoBKGAPhgAYKBWGAH4U6GEmR4A3ACg400JFgBPcaMJxJMAPRaYAUypUQVadIA2e2I1UZsEgiOQzG5yzDA2YhRpp0wLAOaoZu6ohiAA7gCWYAEwqBAQUQFgjHpgsDh6wKgArhB6MIwwURDxZlR6qHRKoeERenQwUCAwAAaobaYAZrlgwFBR4DDdICDMqDbsAN4AvtKj44ysmtq6AOrGANZl3TF6ADSOJWUJSSmoOBbNrWjIC2PMYCswazAAgmYQrXtgetLFfBA9y+XRQKi5PRAA
